# Google Drive .NET Quickstart Erro para obter as Credenciais

Tags: c#, google, google-drive-api

Estou começando a estudar a Api do Google Drive para um projeto pessoal em .NET, e e segui o passo a passo disponibilizado no site da google

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet

Porém quando fui executar o código no momento de obter as credências aconteceu este erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue abaixo o código utilizado:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace TestesGoogleDrive
{
    class Program
    {
        // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
        // at ~/.credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json
        static string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.Drive };
        static string ApplicationName = "Drive API .NET Quickstart";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
                new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            //    credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, "credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json");

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            // Create Drive API service.
            var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

            // Define parameters of request.
            FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
            listRequest.PageSize = 10;
            listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";

            // List files.
            IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute()
                .Files;
            Console.WriteLine("Files:");
            if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", file.Name, file.Id);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No files found.");
            }
            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

Pacotes instalados no projeto conforme está no tutorial, mais configurações no arquivo client_secret.json para sempre copiar na saída conforme também está no tutorial:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já aconteceu este problema com alguém ou algo semelhante ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Consegui encontrar o problema**

O meu problema era que quando eu criar o path para salvar o Token: "Users\NOVA\Documents.credentials\drive-dotnet-quickstart.json". O windows estava barrando o acesso do projeto para criar a pasta neste local, para salvar o Token.

Então para resolver o problema executei o Visual Studio em modo administrado. E aí sim o projeto conseguiu criar a pasta no destino especificado e ocorreu tudo certo...